# How can I export package-scope JSDoc types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc, tsc, tsserver

I'm looking for a workaround for this bug in `tsc`: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50436

## Problem 1:

Package-scoped types are **not available** outside of a package.

1. If you declare a type in `./types.js` (and include that file in `jsconfig.json.include` then that type is scoped to your package - any file can use it. Example:

   ```js
   // types.js
   /**
    * @typedef {Object} Foo
    * @prop {String} name
    */

   // index.js
   /** @type {Foo} */
   let foo;
   ```
2. You **cannot** import that type from another package. Example:

   ```js
   // bar.js
   /** @type {import('foo/types.js').Foo} */
   let foo;

   // ❌ [tsserver] Cannot find name 'Foo'.
   ```

### Problem 2

Exported types are not available in the package-scope.

1. If you add an export to `./types.js`, the types are no longer available at the package level. Example:

   ```js
   // types.js
   module.exports = {}; // causes types to be exported

   /**
    * @typedef {Object} Foo
    * @prop {String} name
    */

   // index.js
   /** @type {Foo} */
   let foo;

   // ❌ [tsserver] Cannot find name 'Foo'.
   ```
2. But now import that type from another package. Example:

   ```js
   // bar.js
   /** @type {import('foo/types.js').Foo} */
   let foo;
   ```

### Reduced Test Case Git Repo

Here's a reduced test case with all the `tsconfig.json`, `package.json`, etc:

https://github.com/coolaj86/test-case-tsc-exports

```
.
├── README.md
├── main.js
├── tsconfig.json
└── node_modules
    ├── bar
    │   ├── bar.js
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── tsconfig.json
    │   └── types.js
    └── foo
        ├── foo.js
        ├── package.json
        ├── tsconfig.json
        └── types.js
```

### Catch 22

How can I both export types *and* have them available in the package scope?

Comment: What you're calling "package scope" is really "global scope"... hacky workaround: create a `types_globals.js` which does `/** @typedef Foo {import("./types").Foo} */` for each export.

Comment: Would you please share a github repo with a minimal reproducible example? Testing it on my side just works.

Comment: @lepsch Here you go: https://github.com/coolaj86/test-case-tsc-exports

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that `foo/types.js` is declaring a global type only accessible in the package it's declared in. This is because `foo/types.js` is not a module so everything becomes global inside it. From the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#top-level-await):

> Files are only considered modules when TypeScript finds an `import` or an `export`. In some basic cases, you might need to write out `export {}` as some boilerplate to make sure of this.

To fix the problem then both `foo/types.js` and `bar/types.js` should have an export like `module.exports = {};` (or the one you've written in `bar/types.js` or even ES modules like `export {}`).

The following are the `types.js` files:

**bar/types.js**

```js
"use strict";

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Bar
 * @property {Number} age
 * @property {2 | 7 | 11 | 37 | 42} lucky_number
 */

module.exports = {};
```

**foo/types.js**

```js
"use strict";

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Foo
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {"vanilla"|"chocolate"|"strawberry"} flavor
 */

 module.exports = {};
```

And to use the type in the package level it must be the same way it is in Typescript, just importing it. This way everything should work as expected.

**bar/bar.js**

```js
"use strict";

/** @type {import('./types.js').Bar} */
let bar = {
    age: 37,
    lucky_number: 37,
};

console.log(bar);
```

**foo/foo.js**

```js
"use strict";

/** @type {import('./types.js').Foo}*/
let foo = {
    name: "JS",
    flavor: "vanilla",
};

console.log(foo);
```

**main.js**

```js
"use strict";

/**
 * @param {import('foo/types.js').Foo} foo
 * @param {import('bar/types.js').Bar} bar
 */
function bazzer(foo, bar) {
    return {
        baz: foo.name,
        qux: foo.flavor,
        quux: bar.age,
        grault: bar.lucky_number,
    };
}

module.exports.bazzer = bazzer;
```

Here's the repo with the fixes inplace: https://github.com/lepsch/test-case-tsc-exports